# Mysql How to update n rows using count function?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, update, count

In the following table, I want to set delete = true if the total records for same orgid exceed 500
and I want to do it according to createdate such that if records exceed 500 the old records get deleted and make total records 500 for that orgid.

here is my table

```
Table A
+----+-------+------------------+--------+------------+
| id | orgid | transactionvalue | delete | createdate |  
+----+-------+------------------+--------+------------+
|  1 |     1 |              123 | false  | 05-16-2020 |  
|  2 |     1 |              412 | false  | 07-16-2020 |  
|  3 |     2 |              762 | false  | 07-16-2020 |  
+----+-------+------------------+--------+------------+
```

Here is the query I am trying

```
update A set delete = true where orgid = 1 and (select count(*) as records from (select * from A order by createdate) as pseudotable)) >500
```

Comment: @nbk yes I want to keep the latest 500 records and delete the 10 oldest records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will update the oldest records that exceed the count of 500, so you keep 500 newest records for `orgid = 1`

```
update A 
set `delete` = true 
where orgid = 1 AND id IN (
SELECT id FROM  A where orgid = 1
order by createdate DESC
LIMIT 500,18446744073709551615);
```

Comment: May as well say `LIMIT 500,1` (since you don't need multiple rows).  Then you may as well switch from `IN` to `EXISTS`.